# How to access data stored in Future<QuerySnapshot> in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

This is repository where I'm accessing data using `getDocumenent()` which return `Future<QuerySnapshot>`

```dart
Future<QuerySnapshot> fetchOrderSummery() async {
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return firestoreInstance
        .collection("placeOrder")
        .document(user.uid)
        .collection("subPlaceOrder")
        .getDocuments();
  }
```

This is my `FutureBuilder`

```dart
Future<QuerySnapshot> order = state.orderSummery;  //Using bloc so data return by state.orderSummery
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: order,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('${order.data.documents}'),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Declare a variable
2. Assign during execution
3. Use the variable in the Future

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> _order;

 _futureSearch = fetchOrderSummery()
return FutureBuilder(
            future: _order,
```